# How to use --undefined=symbol

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

How can I use the flag `--undefined=symbol` correctly to solve the problem of undefined references that has not been packaged into a shared library from a static one?

What should I use in place of `symbol`?

**Some background:**

The error message I am getting is something like:

```
mylib.so: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
```

Where `cv::line` is function that is exist in `libstaticA` that `libstaticB` is linking to it. `libsharedFinal` links to both `libstaticA` and `libstaticB`.

I have been reading about this issue and the available solutions as I could understand are:

- To use Object file instead of static libraries which I can not do for some reason
- Whole Archive: which will cause very heavy shared library
- Using `--undefined=symbol` could be a solution since it will export specific symbols instead of the whole archive

Comment: If `libsharedFinal` links `libstaticA` as well, I don't think you should be having this problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that what I used to know (and BTW it works well on Windows MSVC) But I have spent the whole day without getting it to work on Ubuntu / GCC

Comment: If I were you I would double check what is being linked and what is not. Present your [MCVE] here so we can check too.